# Show div when checkbox id checked but under the all checkboxes

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have a form containing 20 checkboxes.

I want to show the content of a div when a checkbox is checked.
I got a result like that

```css
#toggle-content1 {
  display: none;
}

#mycheckbox1:checked~#toggle-content1 {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
}

#toggle-content2 {
  display: none;
}

#mycheckbox2:checked~#toggle-content2 {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox1" value="0" />
<div id="toggle-content1">
  This content should appear when the checkbox is checked
</div>
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox2" value="0" />
<div id="toggle-content2">
  This content should appear when the checkbox is checked
</div>
```

But if you give it a try the code snippet, you'll notice that the first checkbox move the second one(when opened the div), is there a way to leave the checkbox in one row and display the divs on the others?

The css world is new to me, there is a way to write that code for 20 checkbox without write the css for every div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```css
.content {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}

/*Use + to target only one .content*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked + .content {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  order: -1; /*make all the input on the top*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" value="0">
  <div class="content">
    0)This content should appear when the checkbox is checked
  </div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" value="1">
  <div class="content">
    1)This content should appear when the checkbox is checked
  </div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" value="2">
  <div class="content">
    2)This content should appear when the checkbox is checked
  </div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" value="3">
  <div class="content">
    3)This content should appear when the checkbox is checked
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I simply reordered your tags, input first then divs. But i'm not really sure that's what you want

```css
#toggle-content1 {
  display: none;
}

#mycheckbox1:checked~#toggle-content1 {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
}

#toggle-content2 {
  display: none;
}

#mycheckbox2:checked~#toggle-content2 {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox1" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox2" value="0" />
<div id="toggle-content1">
  This content should appear when the checkbox1 is checked
</div>
<div id="toggle-content2">
  This content should appear when the checkbox2 is checked
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ScnQT/5539/

Answer (score 1):

please have a look below updated code, hope you will find the solutions.

```css
.chkBox{
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
}

.chkTxt{
background:#fff;
padding:10px;
border:1px solid #ccc;
width:500px;
height:100px;
position:absolute;
top:100%;
left:0;
display:none;
}

.chkBox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .chkTxt{
display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="chkBox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox1" value="0" />
  <div class="chkTxt">This content should appear when the checkbox1 is checked </div>
</div>

<div class="chkBox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox2" value="0" />
  <div class="chkTxt">This content should appear when the checkbox2 is checked </div>
</div>


<div class="chkBox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox3" value="0" />
  <div class="chkTxt">This content should appear when the checkbox3 is checked </div>
</div>

<div class="chkBox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox4" value="0" />
  <div class="chkTxt">This content should appear when the checkbox4 is checked </div>
</div>


<div class="chkBox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox5" value="0" />
  <div class="chkTxt">This content should appear when the checkbox5 is checked </div>
</div>
```

Comment: downside with this is that you position it absolute.

Comment: To prevent misplacement of check box i use position absolute. in this way you can repeat/use multiple checkbox in loop there will be no issues. no matter your loop runs 50 or 1000 times

Comment: Yes, that also makes it hard to maintain with dynamic height if you have content below that you don't want to cover when it expands.

Answer (score -2):

I would use a script for this...and in a real application, I would use a model + templating engine.
([Vue engine sample](http://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/eywraw8t/252137/))
This way you can put your output wherever you want and format however you like it. This way you can also load a new datamodel from the server(store your checkbox questions/values/answers in db somwhere) and it would redraw/update your entire page without needing any updates from you.

```
// HTML
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox1" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox2" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox3" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox4" value="4" />
<div id="activeCheckboxes"></div><!-- you can put this anywhere on the page -->

// JavaScript
const checkboxes = {
  1: {checked: false, message: 'First checkbox checked'},
  2: {checked: false, message: 'Second checkbox checked'},
  3: {checked: false, message: 'Third checkbox checked'},
  4: {checked: false, message: 'Fourth checkbox checked'}
};
const activeCheckboxes = document.getElementById('activeCheckboxes');
const updateCheckboxes = () => {
    activeCheckboxes.innerHTML = '';
  Object.keys(checkboxes).forEach((val) => {
    let checkbox = checkboxes[val];
    if (checkbox.checked) {
        activeCheckboxes.innerHTML += '<div>'+checkbox.message+'</div><hr>';
    }
  });
};
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('input[type]="checkbox"').click((evt) => {
    checkboxes[evt.target.value].checked = evt.target.checked;
    updateCheckboxes();
  });
});
```

[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/ScnQT/5573/)